# Склейка видео с помощью ffmpeg

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

Добрый день, встала задача склеить несколько видео в одно (количество видео всегда разное (т.е. возможно 1, возможно 2, возможно n), собственно нагуглил такой вот пример:

```
 ffmpeg -i new_1.mp4 -i new_2.mp4 -i new_3.mp4 -i new_4.mp4 
 -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=640x480 [base]; \
[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperleft]; \
[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperright]; \
[2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerleft]; \
[3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [lowerright]; \
[base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1]; \
[tmp1][upperright]   overlay=shortest=1:x=320 [tmp2]; \
[tmp2] [lowerleft] overlay=shortest=1:y=240 [tmp3]; \
[tmp3][lowerright] overlay=shortest=1:x=320:y=240" -c:v output.mp4
```

в данном примере идет склейка 4-х видео, но не совсем понимаю, возможно ли вместо upperright - писать позицию видео?

пример. положим что канва на которой работает будет 1280 на 768 и у нас есть 6 видео (все видео одинакового размера, но имеют разную продолжительность, положим что размер одного видео 1024 на 768). Пробуем разместить их в две строки, по три видео на строку. получаем следующие размеры для видео:
ширина: 1280/3 = 426 пикселей
высота: 768 / 2 = 384, где 2 - количество строк

собственно вопросы:
1) могу ли я задавать позицию видео не так

`[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperleft];`

а вот так например:

`[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=426x384 [0,384];`

`[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=426x384 [426,384];`

или как-то по другому? как правильно сделать сетку в ffmpeg?

2) в случае с видео, которые разные по времени, по истечению самого короткого видео картинка дальше тормозиться, но звуковая дорожка идет, как решить данные вопрос? подогнать короткое видео по таймингу к самому длинному? тогда как это делается? нечто вроде заполняем 4-ми кадрами остаток?

спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`upperleft` здесь - это не позиция, а псевдоним для потока-результата `scale`.

```
[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=320x240 [upperleft];
```

Взять поток `0:v`, пожать его до 320x240 и обозвать `upperleft` для дальнейшего использования. Здесь видео пока никак не компонуется с другими - только пережимается до нужного размера.

```
[base][upperleft] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1]
```

Взять потоки `base` и `upperleft`, применить `overlay` с такими параметрами и выдать результат в поток `tmp1`. Сами имена потоков могут быть любые. Вот тут как раз и идёт склейка видео.

Позиция оверлея на результирующем потоке - это параметры `overlay` `x` и `y`, которые видны в последних 3 строках. Вот [список](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay-1) возможных параметров. По второму вопросу посмотрите `eof_action` и `repeatlast`

Для 6 видео что-то вроде этого получится:

```
 ffmpeg -i new_1.mp4 -i new_2.mp4 -i new_3.mp4 -i new_4.mp4 -i new_5.mp4 -i new_6.mp4 
 -filter_complex "nullsrc=size=1280x768 [base]; \
[0:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=426x384 [upper1]; \
[1:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=426x384 [upper2]; \
[2:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=426x384 [upper3]; \
[3:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=426x384 [lower1]; \
[4:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=426x384 [lower2]; \
[5:v] setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, scale=426x384 [lower3]; \
[base][upper1] overlay=shortest=1 [tmp1]; \
[tmp1][upper2] overlay=shortest=1:x=426 [tmp2]; \
[tmp2][upper3] overlay=shortest=1:x=852 [tmp3]; \
[tmp3][lower1] overlay=shortest=1:y=384 [tmp4]; \
[tmp4][lower2] overlay=shortest=1:y=384:x=426 [tmp5]; \
[tmp5][lower3] overlay=shortest=1:y=384:x=852" -c:v output.mp4
```